# iOS Crash with name SIGSEGV and reason main

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I'm using Crittercism (SDK 3.5.1) crash reporting service to catch reports on my iOS app.
i've been getting this error many times and i've no idea why it's happening.

**Name: SIGSEGV   -  Reason: Main**

Here is the full report from Crittercism:

```
Threads
_________________________________
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x39917526 objc_retain + 6
1     UIKit                                 0x33a92ab3 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 159
2     UIKit                                 0x33b078ef -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 51
3     QuartzCore                            0x3383cc01 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 209
4     libdispatch.dylib                     0x39d314b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
5     libdispatch.dylib                     0x39d32dcb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 227
6     CoreFoundation                        0x31c48f3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291
7     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
8     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
9     GraphicsServices                      0x3577f2eb GSEventRunModal + 75
10   UIKit                                  0x33ad1301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
11   MyAppName                              0x0002e29b main (main.m:17)

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e08648 kevent64 + 24
1     libdispatch.dylib                     0x39d33df8 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 36

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e07eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x31c4a045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2     CoreFoundation                        0x31c48da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5     WebCore                               0x37bba505 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 445
6     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d71311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e07eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x31c4a045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2     CoreFoundation                        0x31c48da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5     Foundation                            0x325083d5 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6     Foundation                            0x3258be85 __NSThread__main__ + 973
7     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d71311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e07eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1     CoreFoundation                        0x31c4a045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129
2     CoreFoundation                        0x31c48da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883
3     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4     CoreFoundation                        0x31bbbd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5     Foundation                            0x324def97 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 255
6     Foundation                            0x32582865 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7     MyAppName                             0x001000c1 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:182)
8     Foundation                            0x3258be85 __NSThread__main__ + 973
9     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d71311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e18594 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d71311 _pthread_start + 309

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e18d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d66a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e18d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d66a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread: Unknown Name
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x39e18d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x39d66a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366



Crashed Registers
_________________________________
r12 0xb9e49
r10 0x0
r11 0x10
cpsr    0x30
r4  0x1fb79160
r5  0x1f4158
r6  0x33efe80f
r7  0x2fdd9e84
r0  0x1fb16050
r1  0x80000000
r2  0x2
r3  0x790ca8e9
sp  0x2fdd9e78
r8  0x1
r9  0xa25701
pc  0x39917526
lr  0xb9095
```

Comment: Some context would be useful here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First guess would be that a delegate you've set with something like:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
```

has been freed before the animation has finished.

Comment: i've tried to trace the app but i'm not sure in which part it crashes. specially that it does not show in which class the error is happening. does this mean it's in the AppDelegate class?

Comment: It means it's happening when the OS is calling back your delegate. Are you able to reproduce the crash? If so run it in the debugger with nszombies enabled. If not, how many classes do you have that call setAnimationDelegate?

Comment: as you mentioned, this was a animation issue with delegate. many thanks